# Iterate over pandas dataframe and update values in columns for a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a Pandas dataframe with `checkdataframe.shape (68125, 109)`. I want to perform a Operation in all the columns like I did it below for a single list.

```
def alter_column(column,batchSize=10):
return_list=[]
for idx,value in enumerate(column): 
        if (idx+1)%batchSize==1: 
            return_list.append(value)
        else:
            return_list.append(np.nan)
return return_list
```

which Returns a list with values removed over certain intervals of 10 like this Output

```
['175,5200',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,'175,5200',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,'180,0000']
```

I wanted it to do it over entire dataframe . i tried df.iteritems and df.iterrows but it Shows error. Any possible solution or way to do it?

```
eg:df['column1']=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
   df['column2']=[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]
expected_output:
column1=['1',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,'2',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan] column2=['3',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,'4',nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan]
```

But my real dataset has 109 columns

Comment: Please provide a small data sample, as well as the required output. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @Roy2012 I added a sample data and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index of your dataframe is 0 .. n you can apply this:

```py
df[~df.index.isin(np.arange(0, df.shape[0], batchSize))] = np.nan
```

This way you keep only every 10 rows as not np.nan